# Use Vite to create webview in VSCode Extension

Tags: vscode-extensions, vite

I'm trying to use Vite (react-ts) to generate script used in webview on VSCode Extension. (Extension is also written in Typescript.)

Is this possible? And how can I configure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was also looking for a extension sample with react+vite+webview. Turns out that Microsoft's github had an example for the same.

You can find it here:https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-webview-ui-toolkit-samples/tree/main/frameworks/hello-world-react-vite

The structure is a bit different than other extensions but it got's its own advantages.

Hope this helps.